# Simple Way to Use a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I followed the MSDN walkthrough on creating and using a DLL in Visual C++ Studio, but it requires the user to add the DLL project to the same solution as the project they're working on.

Is there a simple way to include a DLL?  Ideally, I'd like to just distribute my `.dll` (and the `.lib`, I suppose) to my friends so they can use it in their own projects.

I realize there are other walkthroughs out there (some of them on SO), but they all require editing the PATH environment variable, etc.  Is that really the simplest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a minimum, you need to do the following:

- Include the `.lib` file in the project
- Tell the linker where you put the `.lib` file (library search path)
- Make the `.dll` file available at runtime (easiest is to put it in the same directory as the `.exe`)

To distribute the compiled `.dll` to your friends, you will need to include:

- the `.h` file(s) for the compiler
- the `.lib` file for the linker
- the `.dll` file for runtime

Comment: How would I include the .lib file in the project and tell the linker where it is?  Just right-click the project and add it as an existing file, then change the path in the property pages?

Comment: I haven't used VS2010 so I'm afraid I can't direct you to the exact spot. However, it will likely be somewhere in the project settings. It may be as simple as adding the `.lib` file to the project (if you explicitly add the `.lib` file by selecting an existing file, then VS will know where to find it).

Comment: Alright.  Also, when you say I need to include the `.h` file, does that mean it has to be as a separate file?  (i.e., not compiled into the `.lib`?)

Comment: Header (`.h`) files are never compiled into `.lib` files, they stand alone. Header files are included in C++ source files with the `#include` directive.

Comment: @Maxpm: Yes. For example, when you install the Windows SDK, you get both the headers (windows.h), the libraries (i.e. shlwapi.lib), and the dlls themselves are provided on the target Windows machine.